# Saving Chat History For Three Months

Tags: flash, flash-media-server

I am working in a chat application using Flash Media Server. I am wanting to save the chat history of the respective user and chat room for future purposes.

Is it possible to save the users chat history in the FMS server itself, or would it need to be saved in a database?

It be good if you have any suggestions or guidelines please?

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy just write the chat to a file named for example instance-user-chat.txt.

When the user returns check for the file and load this when the user returns.